# Accessing computer information within PHP

Tags: php, http, header

I was working with headers for a VPN and proxy detection script I'm currently working on. While I was trying to access my web server with my laptop, it kept triggering the proxy detection function.

So I checked it out. The header being triggered was HTTP_VIA, and I echo'd the contents of the header. On my laptop, it gave out the name of the computer.

Is this a bug? I accessed it through Google Chrome, and Internet Explorer, achieving the same results from each browser.

Comment: Depending on your connection, it is quite possible that your ISP is acting like a proxy.

Comment: 'quite possible' - read 'quite likely'. Many ISPs are implementing transparent caches because it reduces their bandwidth charges. Sometimes they even work properly.